# how to take input in ascii and print it in string?

Tags: java, python, c

```
import string

def main():
    inString =input("enter any number to decode :  ")
    
    message=" "
    for numStr in string.split(instring):
        asciiNum = eval(numStr)
        message = message+chr(asciiNum)
    print("\n", message)
main()
```

Comment: What exactly is the question please?

Comment: Did you mean: message = chr(int(instring)). ?

Comment: btw you hardly ever need to use ‘eval’ in python.

Comment: Please correct your tags. This looks like python, so java and c should be removed.

Answer (score 2):

1. You need to convert the input to int by using `int()` function because the input is a string and ASCII is a int
2. To get the ASCII value, you can use `chr()`

So, for example:

```py
inString = input("enter any number to decode : ")
number_to_decode = int(inString)

print( chr( number_to_decode ) )
```

Answer (score 0):

It should work:

```
def main():
instring = input("enter any number to decode :  ")

message = " "
for numStr in str.split(instring):
    asciiNum = eval(numStr)
    message = message + chr(asciiNum)
print("\n", message)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a Java soln,

```
class AsciiConvertor{

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int asciiVal = 87;
        String strValue = Character.toString((char) asciiVal);
        System.out.println(strValue);
    }
}
```

Output: W